# Fast way to extract neighborhoods from Numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given is a test array with some values that are nonzero.

```
test_arr = np.zeros((10, 10), dtype=int)
test_arr[[0, 1, 4], [0, 0, 8]] = 1 # set some entries to one

indices_r, indices_c = np.nonzero(test_arr)
```

I want to find the **neighboring** cells of points denoted by `(indices_r[0], indices_c[0])` **without** using a for loop. In addition, I want to check for various other flags.

```
# Test mask
test_mask = np.zeros((10, 10))
test_mask[[2, 4], [0, 8]] = 1
test_mask = test_mask.astype(bool)
```

More precisely, I know I could to something like

```
valid_neighs =[]
for r, c in zip(indices_r, indices_c):
    range_r, range_c = np.arange(r-1, r+2), np.arange(c-1, c+2) # Moore neighborhood
    # neighs_r, neighs_c = np.meshgrid(range_r, range_c, indexing="ij")
    
    for rr, cc in zip(neighs_r, neighs_c):
         # Check various flags
         if (0 <= rr <= 10 and 0 <= cc <= 10 
         and mask[rr, cc] is True): # within lattice and mask is True
         valid_neighs.append(rr, cc)
```

I'm looking for a way that eliminates **both** for loops.

That is, I want something like

```
indices = np.array([[valid_neighs_point_1], ..., [valid_neighs_point_N]])
```

such that I can call `test_arr[indices]`.

Comment: What have you got against loops?

Comment: @ScottHunter They are slow? I need to call this function > 10 ** 6 times